# Parse and read xml array

Tags: ruby, xml

This is a simple stuff but driving me really crazy now. Spent hours on figuring this out which I have many many times before.

I am trying to read a parse xmlsimple doc. But I don't know why can't access elements by index number. I can't understand the problem, when I try this in the console it works, but not in actual code. It gives me this error on the view page:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Code:

```
@i = 0
list =""
while @i <= 2
  puts xml
  a = parsed_items["Item"][@i]["ItemId"]
  list <<  a.to_s << ","
  @i += 1
end
puts list.to_s
```

If I do it by giving a int value manually in my code then it works:

```
a = parsed_items["Item"][0]["ItemId"] # it works with other exact code
```

Change to `@i` and not working:

```
a = parsed_items["Item"][@i]["ItemId"] # it does not work with other exact code
```

XML:

```
1.9.2p290 :013 > items = "<ItemList> <Item> <ItemId>123</ItemId> <ItemName>abc</ItemName> <ItemType>xyz</ItemType> <Status>bad</Status> </Item> <Item> <ItemId>456</ItemId> <ItemName>fgh</ItemName> <ItemType>nbv</ItemType> <Status>bad</Status> </Item> </ItemList>"
     => "<ItemList> <Item> <ItemId>123</ItemId> <ItemName>abc</ItemName> <ItemType>xyz</ItemType> <Status>bad</Status> </Item> <Item> <ItemId>456</ItemId> <ItemName>fgh</ItemName> <ItemType>nbv</ItemType> <Status>bad</Status> </Item> </ItemList>" 

1.9.2p290 :014 > parsed_items = XmlSimple.xml_in(items, { 'KeyAttr' => 'name' })
     => {"Item"=>[{"ItemId"=>["123"], "ItemName"=>["abc"], "ItemType"=>["xyz"], "Status"=>["bad"]}, {"ItemId"=>["456"], "ItemName"=>["fgh"], "ItemType"=>["nbv"], "Status"=>["bad"]}]}
```

XML:

```xml
<ItemList>
  <Item>
    <ItemId>123</ItemId>
    <ItemName>abc</ItemName>
    <ItemType>xyz</ItemType>
    <Status>bad</Status>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemId>456</ItemId>
    <ItemName>fgh</ItemName>
    <ItemType>nbv</ItemType>
    <Status>bad</Status>
  </Item>
</ItemList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paraphrased, that error means *"Hey, you put `[]` after something that was `nil`, but `nil` doesn't have that method!"*

You only have 2 items in your array, so when `@i` gets to `2`—**which is the third item in a 0-based list**—the code `parse_items["Item"][@i]` is returning `nil`; when you try to then execute `["ItemId"]` on that value you get the error you stated.

**Simplest change** to fix this:

```
while @i<2 # instead of <=2
```

**Better change** (let Ruby iterate for you):

```
list = ""
parsed_items["Item"].each do |item|
  list << item["ItemId"].to_s << ","
end
puts list
```

**Even better change** (let Ruby do your work for you):

```
puts parsed_items["Item"].map{ |item| item["ItemId"] }.join(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you're defining an instance variable instead of a local one. Also conversing list into a string is completely unnecessary since it's a string from a very beginning. Working code should look somewhat like this:

```
i = 0
list =""
while i <= 2
  puts xml
  a = parsed_items["Item"][i]["ItemId"]
  list <<  a.to_s << ","
  i += 1
end
puts list
```

I strongly suggest you to [read about different variable types](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants).